# how to resolve VERY LARGE URL problem for hyperlink...with jQuery or Javascript calling any perl,php etc. script on back

Tags: javascript, url, hyperlink, ncbi

I have built UI, its like a search engine for BioProcess/Disease--> Genes. e.g., User can query: "Stem Cells" or "brain tumor"and in result it will give 50 to 5000 GeneIDs (essentially those are Numbers representing a uniqe Gene at NCBI database) .

Its free, you can try at : http://proteogenomics.musc.edu/genemesh/

Now, the problem is I am liking those GeneIDs to a NCBI site at once. For upto 200 or 400 GeneIDs  I can get result fine. But for more than 500 GeneIDs I can get "URI TOO LARGE" error or somehow NCBI website can not accept huge query. I am trying to resolve this problem.

Can Javascript, OnClick write a file in UNIX /tmp file? or is there any better solution to this?

Any help/guidelines are great at this point...

thank you so much in advance,
Saurin

URL too LONG:

http://view.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/30980,31208,31442,31789,32083,32855,33156,33392,33498,34309,35197,35974,36057,38545,38701,42945,43162,43256,43288,43739,44900,45339,45775,3772082,260437,393632,406845,379537,379620,399306,100037057,100037058,100037249,10,40,43,60,104,133,174,182,185,186,187,197,207,208,210,238,240,269,284,285,317,324,328,332,335,351,355,356,358,361,366,379,387,388,396,429,462,466,472,482,558,567,573,575,576,577,581,595,596,598,604,648,650,664,672,673,675,706,712,754,761,768,771,800,836,841,842,847,857,860,875,885,889,890,891,902,960,970,978,983,999,1000,1018,1019,1021,1025,1026,1027,1029,1030,1031,1051,1082,1111,1116,1124,1131,1152,1231,1234,1272,1282,1284,1285,1286,1287,1288,1316,1432,1457,1459,1462,1464,1471,1474,1485,1490,1493,1499,1508,1512,1520,1543,1545,1571,1594,1600,1605,1612,1620,1622,1630,1633,1638,1641,1643,1649,1728,1755,1756,1803,1809,1814,1839,1854,1869,1909,1910,1942,1950,1956,1969,2012,2013,2014,2019,2020,2022,2034,2035,2044,2045,2046,2048,2050,2051,2052,2064,2066,2067,2068,2071,2100,2149,2166,2173,2246,2247,2250,2251,2254,2260,2263,2264,2272,2289,2290,2305,2308,2309,2321,2335,2475,2542,2547,2574,2579,2621,2627,2670,2734,2735,2736,2737,2738,2740,2849,2890,2896,2901,2908,2925,2932,2936,2939,2944,2947,2950,2952,2956,3073,3074,3082,3090,3091,3104,3105,3106,3115,3122,3123,3146,3161,3162,3181,3191,3215,3240,3265,3309,3315,3324,3371,3373,3383,3384,3397,3398,3417,3479,3480,3481,3482,3485,3486,3487,3491,3553,3558,3561,3565,3566,3569,3574,3575,3596,3597,3598,3603,3611,3621,3630,3632,3645,3672,3685,3688,3717,3732,3738,3741,3766,3785,3791,3814,3815,3845,3897,3910,3912,3913,3915,3918,3925,3945,3956,3958,3981,3987,4035,4087,4088,4089,4133,4137,4145,4147,4152,4155,4172,4175,4192,4193,4194,4241,4255,4267,4288,4292,4303,4312,4313,4314,4316,4318,4320,4321,4323,4327,4350,4436,4440,4524,4548,4549,4552,4574,4601,4609,4654,4684,4691,4735,4745,4763,4771,4790,4804,4807,4808,4829,4830,4843,4851,4856,4893,4907,4914,4915,4916,4950,4978,4982,5015,5028,5030,5054,5080,5111,5118,5154,5155,5156,5159,5178,5241,5243,5266,5274,5276,5290,5294,5295,5328,5329,5334,5340,5395,5444,5468,5536,5538,5563,5566,5578,5579,5580,5581,5583,5584,5591,5594,5595,5599,5602,5629,5653,5663,5702,5708,5713,5725,5727,5728,5730,5743,5745,5747,5764,5781,5803,5805,5834,5835,5879,5880,5881,5888,5894,5898,5899,5900,5915,5921,5925,5934,5970,5978,5981,5992,6048,6091,6118,6165,6195,6275,6278,6284,6347,6382,6387,6416,6464,6469,6490,6502,6506,6507,6513,6598,6606,6608,6622,6647,6648,6649,6657,6659,6660,6662,6663,6664,6667,6670,6678,6695,6697,6714,6717,6770,6772,6774,6790,6853,6855,6863,6892,6900,6948,7012,7013,7015,7018,7020,7025,7040,7042,7054,7057,7076,7078,7105,7124,7153,7157,7161,7168,7175,7185,7186,7248,7249,7258,7262,7276,7277,7283,7298,7422,7428,7431,7442,7447,7468,7474,7490,7508,7515,7517,7518,7520,7525,7545,7799,7849,7852,7980,8028,8038,8061,8089,8140,8190,8301,8372,8484,8507,8577,8605,8650,8678,8682,8692,8718,8737,8741,8742,8743,8745,8754,8771,8772,8788,8795,8797,8811,8828,8829,8841,8842,8848,8851,8862,8871,8877,8928,8930,9077,9100,9113,9141,9148,9156,9173,9211,9212,9232,9334,9353,9423,9429,9444,9445,9447,9459,9507,9518,9535,9545,9588,9681,9806,9833,9844,9961,10036,10135,10209,10215,10313,10362,10371,10381,10401,10472,10512,10530,10572,10620,10630,10642,10743,10763,10776,10855,10893,10991,11009,11010,11013,11065,11093,11095,11096,11141,11156,11162,11186,11191,11200,11235,11284,22865,22933,22943,23136,23152,23162,23209,23261,23308,23336,23435,23469,23627,23654,23705,25776,25792,25855,26013,26038,26050,26136,26256,26471,26524,27122,28514,29103,29108,29126,29997,29998,30001,50618,50859,50943,51050,51147,51199,51213,51230,51305,51330,51335,51438,51637,51668,51747,51763,53358,53615,53616,54106,54828,55210,55294,55553,55717,55752,55760,55859,56647,56920,57124,57142,57447,57448,57670,60672,63827,64101,64386,64710,64805,65065,79659,79682,79944,80309,80332,80381,80781,81557,83483,83605,83667,83858,84148,84189,84280,84504,84525,84631,84654,84707,84708,91419,92140,112755,114798,116448,116986,121227,129787,139065,140885,146691,146956,160728,162979,163732,200895,253260,253738,259266,284217,284459,286527,338030,342945,375790,399473,406907,406991,407043,646555,728239,100133941,403412,396562,396783,751862,100125840,100125841,282862,100008679,11539,11545,11601,11622,11629,11651,11731,11783,11789,11799,11829,11920,11932,12028,12035,12140,12151,12211,12307,12308,12344,12389,12390,12505,12519,12554,12575,12578,12606,12767,12945,13003,13051,13176,13193,13197,13555,13730,13731,13732,13846,13866,14080,14102,14164,14254,14360,14397,14580,14609,14632,14633,14634,14714,14751,14825,14829,14910,15160,15218,15251,15413,15442,15529,15901,16153,16483,16542,16653,16765,16847,17125,17196,17246,17390,17395,17869,17920,18008,18015,18016,18040,18071,18072,18125,18128,18133,18208,18386,18507,18591,18595,18616,18708,18787,18792,18793,18996,18997,19090,19118,19122,19206,19211,19227,19247,19373,19377,19531,19557,19645,19650,19651,20423,20511,20713,20720,20848,20849,20852,20981,21333,21367,21375,21687,21826,21846,21948,22059,22339,22596,22612,23796,26362,26413,26417,26434,30878,30957,50490,50913,50914,54725,55992,56458,56717,60609,64930,66395,66471,67903,71722,74318,75409,76965,79401,81897,83485,107831,110105,110122,111364,111519,170756,192198,210933,211323,216225,218397,230775,232286,239250,245446,245450,269608,386750,24248,24329,24338,24387,24392,24464,24482,24498,24615,24835,24842,24929,25026,25112,25124,25125,25163,25240,25264,25265,25404,25408,25425,25445,25491,25496,25550,25589,25617,25621,25647,25712,29290,29386,29527,29543,29597,29665,50557,50577,50658,50689,54250,54251,59086,64157,64803,65054,81649,81651,81686,83425,83476,83497,83785,84114,84353,84357,84394,84577,84578,89804,89805,89807,114122,114851,116554,116590,116996,117273,170568,192248,292994,297893,306464,308435,338474,360457,362317,369119,2828259,155871,156110,908122,4981003,4981004,4981005,4981006,4981007,4981008,4981009,4981010,4981011,4981012,4981013,4981014,4981015,4981016,4981017,4981018,4981019,4981020,4981021,4981022,4981023,4981024,4981025,4981026,4981027,4981028,4981029,4981030,4981031,4981032,4981033,4981034,4981035,4981036,4981037,4981038,4981039,4981040,4981041,4981042,4981043,4981045,4981046,4981047,4981048,4981049,4981050,4981051,4981052,4981053,4981054,4981055,4981056,4981057,4981058,4981059,4981060,4981061,4981062,4981063,4981064,4981065,4981066,4981067,4981068,4981069,4981070,4981071,4981072,4981073,4981074,4981075,4981076,4981077,4981078,4981079,4981080,4981081,4981082,4981083,4981084,4981085,4981086,4981087,4981088,4981089,4981090,4981091,4981092,4981093,4981094,4981095,4981096,4981097,4981098,4981099,4981100,4981101,4981102,4981103,4981104,4981105,4981106,4981107,4981108,4981109,4981110,4981111,4981112,4981113,4981115,4981116,4981117,4981118,4981119,4981120,4981121,4981125,4981126,4981128,4981129,4981130,4981131,4981132,4981133,4981134,4981135,4981136,4981137,4981138,4981139,4981140,4981141,4981142,4981143,4981144,4981145,4981146,4981147,4981148,4981149,4981150,4981151,4981152,4981153,4981154,4981155,4981157,4981158,4981159,4981160,4981161,4981162,4981163,4981164,4981165,4981166,4981167,4981168,4981169,4981170,4981171,4981172,4981173,4981174,4981175,4981176,4981177,4981178,4981179,4981180,4981181,4981182,4981183,4981184,4981185,4981186,4981187,4981188,4981189,4981190,4981191,4981192,4981193,4981194,4981195,4981196,4981197,4981198,4981199,4981200,4981201,4981202,4981203,4981204,4981205,4981206,4981207,4981208,4981209,4981210,4981211,4981212,4981213,4981214,4981215,4981216,4981217,4981218,4981219,4981220,4981221,4981222,4981223,4981224,4981225,4981226,4981227,4981228,4981229,4981230,4981231,4981232,4981233,4981234,4981235,4981236,4981237,4981238,4981239,4981240,4981241,4981242,4981243,4981244,4981245,4981246,4981247,4981248,4981249,4981250,4981251,4981252,4981253,4981254,4981255,4981256,4981257,4981258,4981259,4981260,4981261,4981262,4981263,4981264,4981265,4981266,4981267,4981268,4981269,4981270,4981271,944996,946069

Comment: I don't see why this would produce a large URI. Perhaps URI length is not the problem, per se. Unless maybe you have a particular query that references multiple GeneIDs and that total URI is too long? Please edit your post adding an example of a URI that gets a URI too long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot use a cookie, the url is too long.  Write the data to a temp table in a database.  Once the data is saved out, send back an ID, pass that via the URL.  You can do this via a web service call without too much of an issue.

Also, put a timestamp on the table, prune out old data after a set period of time.

Comment: Hi Chris, it seems good idea..but the program is like search engine so, multiple queries will be generated across the UI even by the same user so, I am still thinking about the inserting each GeneID to a temp table... thanks for your reply

Comment: Then don't save the user id in the temp table (temp table, btw, is not really a temp table.  It is a real table for storing data temporarily).  You probably don't need any user specific data anyway.  All you need to store is the sequence to get an id so you can load it later.

Answer (score 5):

You could write them to a cookie, sort of the equivalent of a tmp file. A much better solution would be to POST your data instead of using a GET.

Comment: For cookie...what if the cookies are turned off by  the end user...then how to go around that block?

Comment: I agree with Mike -- POST the data instead of GETting it. I don't think writing them to a cookie would be good though.

Answer (score 4):

There's some information about URL lengths here: http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/misc/urllength.html

Basically, storing large data in a URL is not advisable.

You might want to consider putting the values into a HIDDEN input control and then having the link post that data to your server.

Basically, instead of doing this:

```
<A href="http://view.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/1,2,3,4,5">Link Here</A>
```

Try doing this:

```
<FORM action="http://view.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" id="genes" name="genes">1,2,3,4,5</input>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</FORM>
```

Comment: I have tried that , if I put values in a hidden control or hidden input box or display:none DIV... how can I read those hidden values from a NEW WINDOW one by one..to post data to the server for info. retrival..!?

Comment: Bio Researchers would like to see those 10000 GeneIDs at ONCE to see...which they are interested in and also, NCBI server does not accommodate more than 500 GeneIDs at once..!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead of retrieving all the results at once, you could do an AJAX retrieval of the NCBI information for each GeneID when the user clicks on it, adding the results in to the page.

Comment: I think thats what I like to do..but with 5000 GeneIDs how can I query AJAX on new window...because  on same page i have multiple results with lots of GeneIDs..!!?

Comment: What I mean is pulling in the AJAXed information to the *current* page, not a new one, and only doing so for the specific GeneIDs the user clicks on, not all of them.

Comment: oh, you are correct in a way..but the problem is i need to create a new window in order to show the info. because user might click on multiple SETS of GeneIDs...!! I know this is diff. for me to explain....!! but I just found this STACKOVERFLOW...website and its FANTASTIC...and you guys are great..!!